# Cursor creation

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, cursor

I have 2 tables:

Tresent-JanOrg (Rate, Qty)

```
Rate (2, 5, 7)
Qty  (3, 7, 7)
```

Temp (JanOrg)

```
Pkid JanOrg FebOrg MarOrg
1     2        0     0
```

I have to do the calculations 3 times (3 rows in Tresent) to calculate

```
JanOrg = (JanOrg * Qty * Rate) / 100
```

and the total of janorg should then be updated in temp table under janorg

So logically

```
JanOrg = ((2 * 2 * 3) / 100) + ((2 * 5 * 7) / 100) + ((2 * 3 * 7) / 100)))
```

I am trying to use a cursor in SQL Server 2012 but it is not returning correct results

Can you please suggest the better way of performing these calculations as i tried the below code :

```
OPEN complex_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM complex_cursor INTO @rate, @qty

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #temp 
    SET JANORG = (JANORG * @rate * @qty) / 100 

    FETCH NEXT FROM complex_cursor INTO @rate, @qty
END

CLOSE complex_cursor
DEALLOCATE complex_cursor
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You should try **NOT** to use a cursor! That would be smart and efficient..... cursors are the devil - **avoid them** whenever and wherever you can

Comment: @marc_s Could you provide more information on why cursors are so bad, and the alternatives?

Comment: @Kupiakos: SQL is a **set-based** system - it is *quite different* from procedural languages like C#, VB etc. in that you don't do things **row-by-row** (or item by item), specifying each and every single step in the process - to write **good** SQL, you need to rethink your approach and work in a **set-based** mind set and just tell SQL *what* to do - not **HOW** to do it (it'll figure that out itself, and typically much more efficiently than you do it yourself).

Comment: @Kupiakos: see e.g.  [The Road To Professional Database Development: Set-Based Thinking](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/the-road-to-professional-database-development-set-based-thinking/) and a great many more excellent article on the topic - just search for **SQL set-based thinking** and you should find **plenty** of material to look at

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the information. I figured *why* not to use cursors would be more useful for those viewing this question, although I couldn't exactly distinguish what the problem considering cursors are commonplace in DB APIs in procedural languages (which makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this `SELECT`, you can see the values in question - are those values correct in your opinion?

```
SELECT 
    tjo.*, temp.JanOrg,
    (1.0 * tjo.Rate * tjo.Qty * temp.JanOrg) / 100.0
FROM 
    dbo.TresentJanOrg tjo
CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.TempJanOrg temp
```

Output:

```
Rate   Qty   JanOrg (No column name)
------------------------------------
  2     3      2       0.120000
  5     7      2       0.700000
  7     7      2       0.980000
```

And if you sum up those three values, you should get what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @Result DECIMAL(10,4)

SELECT @result = SUM((1.0 * tjo.Rate * tjo.Qty * temp.JanOrg) / 100.0)
FROM dbo.TresentJanOrg tjo
CROSS APPLY dbo.TempJanOrg temp

SELECT @result
```

Returns a value of **1.8000**.

***ABSOLUTELY NO CURSORS NEEDED***

A single, pretty simple **set-based** statement does it all - and so much faster than any **RBAR** (row-by-agonizing-row) processing with a cursor or a while loop....

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response i added this details in the temporary table

Comment: The thing is that i need to do the calculations and then check in table named estimates which already contain this data and in case if the data for same itemid exists then i need to update this table for the corresponding itemid else insert a new row with these calculated operations for this itemid

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is best to do this without a cursor, but I believe that the root of the problem is that your code was doing integer math.

Try these two:

```
SELECT ((2 * 2 * 3) / 100) + ((2 * 5 * 7) / 100)+((2 * 3 * 7) / 100)
SELECT ((2.0 * 2.0 * 3.0) / 100.0) + ((2.0 * 5.0 * 7.0) / 100.0)+((2.0 * 3.0 * 7.0) / 100.0)
```

The first returns 0 and the second returns 1.24.

If you want floating point math, make sure all values/variables are floats.  If you have an int variable, you can cast.  For example:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 2
SELECT 5.0 / CAST(@i AS float)
```